# PHP script to run 24/7

Tags: php, windows, cron

Is it possible to run a PHP script so it will work 24/7 and in case of crash or anything would just be restarted? It shouldn't be opened in browser, but somehow server-side like by cron... It's on Windows server.

Comment: You might want to consider something not written in PHP for this... PHP was not designed for such a job, and other languages might provide better framework functions for long-running processes such as process and thread management (and might save CPU resources and power, depending on how you develop the whole thing). Or if you can, have it run by cron and make it a short-running process (which could do work in small work units; you will still have to ensure that it does not run simultaneously though, e.g. using PHP's `flock()`).

Comment: big +1 for using something other than PHP. wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Run two scripts - each one will check the second one if it is alive :-) - and turn off time limits in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Have one script that is run every `n` minutes.  The first thing it should do is check if it is already running.  If so, the new script exits.

Once that check is complete, do something to mark the script's existence.  The standard is to write your `pid` to a specified location.  Then the check function can:

1. Verify that the `pid` file exists.  No file, no running script.
2. Verify that the `pid` indicated in the file is running.  No running `pid`, no running script.

There is a slight chance  that you will get a false positive of a running file.  For example, your script gets a `pid` of 12345.  When it dies, the system has cycled through all its possible `pid`s.  Now, another process is using `pid` 12345.  The pidfile will contain '12345'; your script will verify that a process with that number is running, see that the new process is there, and assume your script is going.

There is probably a way around this last problem, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible - but the standard reference counting memory manager won't cope with complex object linking. You may need to recompile to enable the circular reference checking garbage collector.

A better solution would be to run a script which completes quickly - and run it frequently using the scheduler (but do think about how it will behave if an instance starts before the previous one completes).

Alternatively you might want to handle the required processing on a stochastic basis, triggered by an HTTP request - but after the synchronous part of the HTTP request has completed (go read up on how garbage collection works in session management).

It would have been helpful to know what the script is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

run your script every minutes and check if last one is stil running or not.

```
$path = '/home/.../domains/..../public_html/.../lasttime.txt';
$myfile = fopen($path, "r");
$last_time = intval(fread($myfile,filesize($path)));
fclose($myfile);

if( (time()-$last_time)<30  ){
    die();
}
```

update this file  inside your script to prevent running another one

```
$myfile = fopen($path,"w");
fwrite($myfile,time()); 
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score -1):

On a windows server you won't be creating cron jobs, the equivalent is the Task Scheduler which can be used to run the scripts on an automated basis.

Like other posts already stated, creating a php script that would run for a short time, but could be invoked once an hour or so is the best way to go.  If you actually need a program to truly run 24/7, you'll need some way to compile your code to binary.  Best bet would be C++ or Java.

Comment: No reason why a script can't run 24/7, what advantage do compiled languages have in this area?